# Problema con Magento y Apache. Como habilitar el módulo "mod_rewrite" en Apache 2.4.9 (En Windows)?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, magento2

Acabo de instalar Magento y cuando intento acceder a la página de admin y a la home page, estas me cargan sin estilos. La documentación oficial de Magento me dice que debo habilitar el módulo "mod_rewrite" de Apache. Lo hice de la siguiente forma:

- Abrí el fichero httpd.conf de Apache y descomenté la línea: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
- Luego remplacé: `AllowOverride none por AllowOverride All`

en dicho fichero y nada, me sigue cargando sin estilos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error o la ruta (asumo que es un error 404) de los estilos que ves en la consola? Los archivos de JS cargan bien?

Comment: Te sale algún error en consola (F12)? Es probable que las direcciones no esten bien mapeadas.

Comment: Las rutas de los estilos estan bien, de eso se encarga el Magento, de todas formas pongo un ejemplo: '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://localhost/Magento/index.php/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">' y en consola me sale el siguiente error: 'TypeError: require.config is not a function'. Perdon si no se entiende mis comentarios, soy nueva aqui

Comment: Al parecer sí, es un error 404 a la hora de encontrar los CSS pero no se como solucionar esto (soy nueva con Magento). @Shaz

Comment: Ya hiciste en la consola: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucioné usando otra versión del Magento, al parecer estaba usando una dañada, estuve varios días con el problema hasta que decidí volverlo a descargar y problema resuelto. No se al final si era que la versión que tenía antes estaba dañada o se me descargó con algún fallo, no se de que manera, pero esa fue la solución a la que pude llegar. Gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: ¿Versiones para Linux y Windows de Magento? Eso es totalmente falso, no existen versiones distintas según el sistema operativo.

Comment: Si, tiempo después me di cuenta que era imposible, pero se arregló cuando descargué y usé otra versión, u otra compilación de la misma versión, no se por que ni como, pero lo solucioné así

Answer (score 2):

No hay versión Magento para Windows y Linux separadas, cada versión de magento debe funcionar en ambas plataformas siendo Linux la más recomendada, donde puede diferenciar es si el servidor es Apache o Nginx. Para que no cargue las librerías JS o CSS debe ser por el mod_rewrite y si lo habilitaste tal vez te faltó reiniciar el apache en ese momento.

Comment: Oh, bueno.... no se entonces que sería lo que pasó, pero cuando usé entonces otra versión fue cuando funcionó bien. (Ambas versiones las descargue del sitio oficial). Y sí, había reiniciado el apache después que habilité el mod_rewrite. Gracias por aclararme esto de todas formas.